# Flutter Run failed in clone project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I copy a project from a folder then I paste in another folder. And when I open it in android studio then this project not build. Showing some error.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\NTH.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\518cb1a6f0b0a7c96a4aac4218e13c11\jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\NTH.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1978c8540575e4da29114a40e6bf1a1a\core-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 17s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

Comment: Do flutter clean, flutter pub get and flutter pub upgrade and try again

Comment: I tried but no luck.

Comment: got the error. in your build.gradle file minCompileSdk is 30 while your dependency has 31 please change your minCompileSdk to 31 and try again by flutter clean and run again